# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'DB_USER' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php on line 26

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this error that i find in  /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php,

but i cant find the error

```
<?php

/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wp_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '99.99.99.99');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');


define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');
```

everything seems to be correct from my point of view, what i am missing?

Victor

Comment: Have you had a look at the missing quote in the fourth line?

Comment: Take a close look at the syntax highlighting here on SO. It easily reveals the problem - a proper editor will give you the same (or similar) highlighting.

Comment: @smith Why don't you actually vote to close it?

Comment: @Mike Vote to *close* requires 3000 reputation. ;-) Simply flagging is 15 reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @Qirel Ah, I thought it was less..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax error. You missed a closing quote in 3 line after `wordpress_db`.

Change

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db);
```

to

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db');
```

It will resolve your problem.